# Trigger action on controller from route after model has resolved in Ember

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js, coffeescript

I am fairly new to Ember, being a hardcore backbone aficionado for many years and I'm at a loss for how to handle a situation I've run into.

I am using [Pusher](http://pusher.com/) and the [Pusher Ember](https://github.com/jamiebikies/ember-pusher) library to build a sort of chat application.

The way it works is, a person navigates to a users account page and it creates a new "conversation".  Then, once that conversation has been created, I would like to subscribe to a pusher channel that is dynamically named after that conversations id. I need to define the Pusher Subscriptions on my controller.

Here's my route (in coffeescript)

```
App.ConversationShowRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: (params) ->
    @store.createRecord('conversation', user_id: params.user_id).save()
```

and my controller:

```
App.ConversationShowController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  init: ->
    subscriptions = []
    subscriptions[@model.get('id')] = ['newMessage']
    PUSHER_SUBSCRIPTIONS: subscriptions
```

Unfortunately, the model has not resolved at this point so I don't yet know what my `@model.id` is, and it fails.

Any advice for the best way to handle this?

Comment: I noticed you are not returning anything from the model, did you try  `return @store.createRecord('conversation', user_id: params.user_id).save()` ?

Comment: @Hrishi i believe in coffeescript it returns the last line in a function by default. Regardless I tried that and no dice. I believe `init` gets called when the controller is first instantated but the promise from the record saving has not yet returned, hence no id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue when I added ember-pusher to my application. The solution I went with is to define a variable in the App namespace that could be referenced. (Not ideal and something I'll need to fix later)

```
init: function () {
  this.channelName = 'presence-document-' + App.documentId + '-channel';
  this.PUSHER_SUBSCRIPTIONS[ this.channelName ] = [
    'pusher:subscription_succeeded', 'pusher:member_added', 'pusher:member_removed',
    'client-send-status', 'client-send-message'
  ];
  this._super();
}
```

A second, cleaner option, would be to try a needs relationship with your user controller, but I'm not sure if that will be available until after init is complete.

```
App.ConversationShowController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ['user'],
  userId: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.user.id'),

  init: function() {
    this.PUSHER_SUBSCRIPTIONS[this.get('userId')] = ['newMessage'];
    this._super(); // Maybe try putting this first if properties haven't resolved.
  }
});
```

A third option would be to lookup the user controller (singleton) during init.

```
App.ConversationShowController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  init: function() {
    var userController = this.container.lookup('controller:user');
    this.PUSHER_SUBSCRIPTIONS[userController.get('id')] = ['newMessage'];
    this._super();
  }
});
```

**UPDATE**

Since you need the conversation id you can observe when the model changes and wire up pusher the way ember-pusher/bindings.js does.  You would no longer need to override controller.init, just set `PUSHER_SUBSCRIPTIONS: {}` to start with.

```
afterModelLoad: function() {
    this.channelName = 'conversation-' + this.get('model.id');
    this.PUSHER_SUBSCRIPTIONS[this.channelName] = ['newMessage'];

    // From bindings.js init
    var events = this.PUSHER_SUBSCRIPTIONS[this.channelName];
    this.pusher.wire(this, this.channelName, events);

    this.removeObserver('afterModelLoad'); /* If you only want to run once */
}.observes('model')
```

Comment: This is very informative. Unfortunately I don't think it will work still as I am not using the userId for the channel name, but rather the conversationId, which is created when you navigate to the conversation page, so there's no way for me to know what it is until you get to the page.

Comment: I just updated my answer to include an observer for model where you can connect once the model is loaded.

Comment: awesome @jheth! Observers!